# SegFault after the call of pthread_join

Tags: c

I am new to threads and I have problem using pthread_join.

This is my code :

```
int             create_threads(t_lemin *lem)                                                  
{                                                                                             
  int           i;                                                                            
  pthread_t     **threads;                                                                    
  int           j;                                                                            
  void          *ret;                                                                         
  t_tree        *tmp;                                                                         

  j = -1;                                                                                     
  printf("starting algo\n");                                                                  
  threads = xmalloc(sizeof(pthread_t));                                                       
  i = count_leaf(lem->start);                                                                 
  tmp = lem->start;                                                                           
  printf("%d\n", tmp->visited[0]);                                                            
  while (++j != i)                                                                            
    {                                                                                         
      tmp->leaf[j]->thread_nbr = j;                                                           
      pthread_create(threads[j], NULL, find_way_out, tmp->leaf[j]);                           
      usleep(100);                                                                            
    }                                                                                         
  i = -1;                                                                                     
  while (++j != i)                                                                            
    (void)pthread_join (*threads[j], &ret);                                                   
  //printf("%d\n", *((int*)ret));                                                             
    return (0);                                                                               
}
```

One of my thread finished his work and after the second one finish, I have a Segmentation Fault.
My functions find_way_out returns pthread_exit((void*)j); or pthread_exit(0);
where j is a integer pointer.
Do you have an idea where it can comes from ?

Thanks !

Comment: What's xmalloc? where do you allocate memory for `threads` elements?

Comment: xmalloc is just a function that verify malloc and exit if malloc failed. It returns void * .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you should pass a pointer to an actual `pthread_t` variable as first argument to `pthread_create`, as a way of emulating *pass by reference*, `pthread_create` will then initialize the object.

Since you pass an uninitialized pointer, you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when `pthread_create` dereferences the pointer. And *you* will have it too when you try to dereference the pointer for the `pthread_join` call.

And it's even worse, since you only allocate space for *one single* `pthread_t` object, so you will go way out of bounds of the "array".

And then for the `pthread_join` loop, you will have `j` being some small positive number, while `i` is a negative number, meaning your loop will iterate *a lot* since it has to iterate until `j` overflows and becomes negative and then continue looping until `j` equals `-1`.

Instead I suggest these changes:

- Use a variable-length array for the `pthread_t` object
- Save the "size" of the array in a variable that you don't change
- And finally, use `for` loops instead

Something like

```
size_t count = count_leaf(lem->start);
pthread_t threads[count];

for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    pthread_create(&threads[i], ...);

...

for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i will apply it.